# Properly scaling the UI canvas for android phone's

Tags: c#, android, canvas, unity-game-engine, scale

So i have been trying for a while now, and i have had almost every topic available. but i just cant seem to get it to work.

So my issue is as following: 
I'm developping for my galaxy s7 with a resolution of 1440 x 2560 pixels.
This is what i use in the game view to properly allign buttons etc.
However i just cant seem to get it to scale properly to other android phones.

I used the canvas scaler alot but no luck so far, might be doing something wrong?

any idea's would be highly, highly appreciated!

Comment: You can check [here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) for a lot of good resources. Keep in mind your game aspect can vary from one device to another: the resolution isn't much of a problem since the _CanvasScaler_ will resize it but the way your elements are anchored, attached to each other, ... will make your game feel the same on various devices. Also, including pictures of your UI on your S7 and on another phone would have been great.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will take a good look at the link you gave me and test a bit(although i already tried). Will let you guys know what the outcome is including some screenshots. Thanks!